# Selenium IDE and telling it to record actions

Tags: ruby, flash, silverlight, selenium, selenium-ide

I am trying to make a little application to allow to record actions within a Flash and Silverlight application. In such manner that you can compile your interactive application in test-mode and then be able to click on elements which then passed the action to Selenium IDE which then adds this command to the testcase.

I am curious if this even possible and how I can achieve this in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new plugin for Se-IDE called 'Flex Pilot X' which works with External Actions exposed through Flex Pilot. Adam Christian (who wrote it) demonstrated it at the SFSE meetup last month; which was recorded and viewable at http://saucelabs.com/blog/index.php/2010/04/highlights-from-our-april-20th-selenium-testing-tools-demo-night/

-adam